# Remove '0' from numbers less than and equal 9

Tags: c++

How can I have an output of

Sample Input No.1:
9

Sample Output No.1:
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9

If you input numbers less than or equal to 9, the output should be (1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9)

And if you input numbers greater than 9, for example:

Sample Input No.2:
20

Sample Output No.2:
01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08.09.10
11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20

My code below is for Sample Input & Output No.2. I tried adding another for loop for SAMPLE NO.1 but it still reads Sample No.2 code. What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a, num;
    cin >> num;

    if (num > 100 || num <= 1){
        cout << "OUT OF RANGE";
    }
    else {
        for (int a = 1; a < num; a++){
            cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << a << ".";
        }
        cout << num;
    }

}
```

kind of new to programming, don't know much

Comment: `setw(num > 9 ? 2 : 1)`?

Comment: What @Jarod42 shows is kind of a short way of doing : for  if(num >9) std::setw(2); else std::setw(1).  And is called the conditional operator and you can learn more about it here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other. You might not know much yet, but you got the ingredients for your code right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a possible solution, you could read the input as a string, then convert it to an integer.

Use the string length as the field width for the `setw` manipulator.

This should be able to handle values of (theoretically) arbitrary length.